# C# Can't retrieve secret from Azure Key Vault

Tags: c#, azure, azure-keyvault

I am trying to retrieve a secret from Azure Key Vault (without using credentials, like in this tutorial: [example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/tutorial-net-create-vault-azure-web-app)):

```
public static async Task<string> GetSecret(string secretName)
{
   try
   {
       return (await GetClient().GetSecretAsync(keyVaultUrl, secretName)).Value;
   }
   catch (KeyVaultErrorException)
   {
      return null;
   }
   catch (Exception ex)
   {
      return null;
   }
}

public static async Task<string> GetAccessTokenAsync()
{
    AzureServiceTokenProvider azureServiceTokenProvider = new AzureServiceTokenProvider();
    return await azureServiceTokenProvider.GetAccessTokenAsync("https://vault.azure.net");
}

private static KeyVaultClient GetClient()
{
   AzureServiceTokenProvider azureServiceTokenProvider = new AzureServiceTokenProvider();
   using KeyVaultClient keyVaultClient = new KeyVaultClient(new KeyVaultClient.AuthenticationCallback(azureServiceTokenProvider.KeyVaultTokenCallback));
   return keyVaultClient;
}
```

but when I call `GetSecret()` I get an

> object reference not set to an instance of an object

exception.

I am pretty sure that the secret does in fact exist in the key vault.

My key vault url is formatted like "https://my-keyvault.vault.azure.net".

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is a NullReferenceException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: You have a `using` in the GetClient() function. It means the client is disposed before returning it. Put the using in the code where you are using the client, not in the GetClient() function.

Comment: @juunas Wow, I'm stupid. Feel free to answer the question so that I can upvote.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you have a using statement in your `GetClient` function, the KeyVaultClient is disposed as soon as the function returns.
Remove the using there and move it to where you use the client.

```
private static KeyVaultClient GetClient()
{
   AzureServiceTokenProvider azureServiceTokenProvider = new AzureServiceTokenProvider();
   KeyVaultClient keyVaultClient = new KeyVaultClient(new KeyVaultClient.AuthenticationCallback(azureServiceTokenProvider.KeyVaultTokenCallback));
   return keyVaultClient;
}
```

```
public static async Task<string> GetSecret(string secretName)
{
   try
   {
       using var client = GetClient();
       return (await client.GetSecretAsync(keyVaultUrl, secretName)).Value;
   }
   catch (KeyVaultErrorException)
   {
      return null;
   }
   catch (Exception ex)
   {
      return null;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I test in my site and the code you provided is almost right. Make sure you have login your account in Visual Studio which you create your key vault.

And remove `using` in code and install [nuget](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.KeyVault/).

```
private static KeyVaultClient GetClient()
{
   AzureServiceTokenProvider azureServiceTokenProvider = new AzureServiceTokenProvider();
   KeyVaultClient keyVaultClient = new KeyVaultClient(new KeyVaultClient.AuthenticationCallback(azureServiceTokenProvider.KeyVaultTokenCallback));
   return keyVaultClient;
}
```